# Finding subgroups of an external direct product of integers modulo

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

It's been a while since I did this.

I have the external direct product $Z_{6}\oplus Z_{2}$.

I would like to determine the subgroups of $Z_{6}\oplus Z_{2}$.

I recall that the subgroup of any integer modulo n $Z_{n}$ is of the form $\left \langle n/k \right \rangle$ for a positive divisor k of n.

Any help to jolt my memory is greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It will be easier to see what they look like if you rewrite as $Z_3 \oplus (Z_2\oplus Z_2)$.

Comment: What you have stated follows from the fact that GCD of 3 and 2 is 1. But how does this relate to finding subgroups? I need a huge jolt.

Comment: I would add that I think there should be 6 possible unique subgroups.

Comment: The way I wrote is easier because subgroups of a direct product of groups of coprime orders are direct products of subgroups, so the only thing you need to do is find the subgroups of each factor. There are more than $6$ of them in total.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the canonical projection $\mathbb Z \times \mathbb Z \to \mathbb Z_6 \times \mathbb Z_2$.

Then the subgroups of $\mathbb Z_6 \times \mathbb Z_2$ correspond to the subgroups of $\mathbb Z \times \mathbb Z$ that contain $6\mathbb Z \times 2\mathbb Z$.

So, start with a [description of the subgroups of $\mathbb Z \times \mathbb Z$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/193863/find-all-subgroups-of-mathbbz-times-mathbbz).