# Can every finite index subgroup of $\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}$ be written as $\langle n\cdot e_1,m\cdot e_2\rangle$?

Tags: group-theory

Can every finite index subgroup of $\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}$ be generated by $n\cdot e_1,m\cdot e_2$ for some integers $n,m$ and some choice of generators $e_1,e_2$ of $\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}$?

Comment: Yes. See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/193863/find-all-subgroups-of-mathbbz-times-mathbbz/194092#194092

Comment: This is true in general, and can be seen using the Smith normal form of the matrix that maps $\mathbb{Z}^n$ to its finite index subgroup.