# How many surjective homomorphisms from $\mathbb{Z}^2$ to $\mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z}$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

> 1. How many surjective homomorphisms from $\mathbb{Z}^2$ to $\mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z}$ are there?
> 2. How many subgroups of $\mathbb{Z}^2$ with index 3 are there?

I really have no idea... please help.

Comment: See also https://math.stackexchange.com/a/194092/589.

Comment: [Here are some tips on how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/9960#9960).

Answer (score 1):

Group homomorphisms $\mathbb Z^2 \to H$ are completely determined by where you send generators, since $\phi(a,b)=\phi(a,0)+\phi(0,b)$ and each of those are determined where $(1,0)$ and $(0,1)$ go.

In other words, the question can be recast by asking how many functions are there

$$f:\{(0,1),(1,0)\} \to \mathbb Z/3 \mathbb Z$$

since each function can be extended to a group homomorphism $\mathbb Z^2 \to H$.

To get a surjective homomorphism, we just require that $f$ is not trivial (doesn't map both basis elements to $0$.)

Comment: Sorry about the confusion... if ($\mathbb{Z}^2)^+$ is the same as $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ then are there not only 2 surjective homomorphisms since we must have the identity mapped to the identity, which leaves us with mapping 1 to either 1 or 2 in $\mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z}$?

Comment: There are no surjective homomorphisms $\mathbb Z/2 \mathbb Z \to \mathbb Z/3 \mathbb Z$. In fact, there are no surjective *functions* $\{0,1\} \to \{0,1,2\}$.