# Finding all subgroups of $\mathbb{Z}^2$ using algebraic topology.

Tags: abstract-algebra, general-topology, group-theory, algebraic-topology, covering-spaces

**Finding all subgroups of $\mathbb{Z}^2$ using algebraic topology.**

I want to find all the subgroups of $\mathbb{Z}^2$ using algebraic topology, I know that $\mathbb{Z}^2$ acts in a properly discontinuous way in $\mathbb{R}^2$ by means of translation and so $p:\mathbb{R}^2\to \mathbb{R}^2/\mathbb{Z}^2\cong \mathbb{S}^1\times\mathbb{S}^1$ is a universal covering space, so that any $H\subset \mathbb{Z}^2$ subgroup corresponds to a $p: \mathbb{R}^2/H\to \mathbb{R}^2/\mathbb{Z}^2\cong \mathbb{S}^1\times\mathbb{S}^1$ covering space. .

Comment: I think, that also using algebraic topology, the proof is somewhat similar to the given ones at this [duplicate](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/193863/find-all-subgroups-of-mathbbz-times-mathbbz); only translated into algebraic topology language.

Comment: This seems difficult because it is sort of backwards. The idea would be to determine all of the coverings of the torus and then reason about what subgroups of the universal cover they correspond to. The problem is that classifying coverings usually involves looking at subgroups of the fundamental group, which we are not allowed here. So we need a different approach. Perhaps one, along the lines of the proof in Hatcher that any covering of a graph is a graph, which takes advantage of the CW-structure of the torus might work.